# Adobe After Effects: Keep "Expression-Relations" when duplicating multiple layers

Tags: duplicates, expression, adobe, after-effects

just wanted to ask, whether there is a way to keep the relations of expressions going when duplicating layers.
E.g. I have two layers, "LayerA" and "LayerB". Now I have an expression going on in "LayerB" saying, that its position always equals the position of "LayerA".
Now when I duplicate those two and get "LayerA 2" and "LayerB 2" I want the expression in "LayerB 2" to reference to "LayerA 2"'s position rather than "LayerA"'s position!

While it is no problem to simply change the expression when there is only one of them, it gets quite hard when you have multiple expressions going on ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might end up wanting to organize your comp differently, but, given your example (and exactly those name lengths), this position expression will work to find the appropriate 'target layer':

```
//base name to work from:
baseName = "Layer";
//length of that:
nameLen = baseName.length;
//this layer's name:
myName = thisLayer.name;
if (myName.length == nameLen) {
 //if they are the same, then it is the original
 // (non-duplicated) version
  thisComp.layer("LayerA").transform.position;
} else {
  //get tail string, the space and number:
  tailStr = myName.substring(nameLen+1, myName.length);
  //build new target layer name with "A":
  targetName = myName.substring(0, (nameLen)) + "A" + tailStr
  //new line pointing to target layer:
  thisComp.layer(targetName).transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would you organise it differently? I'm curious, because I found my way of doing it highly complicated (having to write an expression). I wanted to have text with a automatically resizing background-panel. However the text was meant to be a bit displaced to the front in relation to its background. But when I put both (background and text) in a subcomp it turned out just to be a plain panel. So is there an option to save something as a template or idk :(

Comment: Hi, @CrazyQwert. Well, it's hard 2 know w/o seeing what y're dealing with, but you've given a pretty good description. I've had similar set-ups. Sounds like you wanted the expression working before you copied & organized layers. You could make (for example) 200 'targeting' layers, rename them sequentially (see crgreen.com/aescripts for my renaming scripts), then make one of the 'target' layers, then dupe that & rename those, turn them off, work on the expression on one, then paste the expression to 199 layers. That's one way. What do you mean by 'it turned out just to be a plain panel'?

Comment: Sorry, that it took me so long to answer, was busy with school recently.
I really appreciate you trying to help me!
To make my problem a bit more clear I made a video where I explain it in detail:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Hxhdr910Xs
Maybe this is a bit more understandable!
Thanks again for your efforts :)

Comment: You're suffering from expression over-use. The general rule is that one shouldn't use expressions if the effects they give can be done in another way. It seems you aren't familiar with parenting, which will help with a large part of your problem. You should be using parenting to get the text layers' background and track-matte layers to do what you want. You could perhaps keep the expression that links the color (or opacity or whatever it is) to the other logo object, but I don't see why parenting isn't used here. I'm assuming the text/bg reveal animation is done with keyframes.

Comment: @CrazyQwert, feel free to send me email to continue this outside of SO. See crgreen.com/index2.html for my address.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I've now watched some tutorials on parenting on youtube and see, what I've been missing out on ...

If you don't mind I will send you an E-mail if I run into any other problems in the future (I promise, I won't spam you ;) )

Thanks, one more time, for you help! You are awesome :)